# Sort timestamps (including future) by absolute distance from "now"

Tags: postgresql, datetime, sql-order-by, postgresql-8.2

With a `date` field I can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12402084/96588):

```
ORDER BY ABS(expiry - CURRENT_DATE)
```

With a `timestamp` field I get the following error:

> function abs(interval) does not exist

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2 has reached end-of-life in Dec. 2011. Consider [upgrading to a current version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it (it's not my decision).

Comment: @Charles: I intended to start the transition from [order-by] to [sql-order-by] according to the discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141455/169168). Do you disagree?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, oh, no, I just hadn't noticed that topic.  Yeah, sounds like a sane plan.  Looks like 1500 questions still... good luck.  I'll throw in some help if I get some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (and gives the correct sorting):

```
ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM expiry - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Unfortunately, as Erwin Brandstetter pointed out, it reduces the granularity of the sorting to a full day.

Comment: This should basically work, but simplifies everything to a matter of days, thereby lumping all timestamps together indiscriminately in between 24h-ranges of data. If you want to go with [`EXTRACT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) use `epoch` or `milliseconds` instead of `DAY`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: `MILLISECONDS` seems to be modulo the day, so that results in "random" sorting. But `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM expiry) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())` works beautifully. Could you make this your answer?

Comment: Right, `milliseconds` would have to be *in addition* to `day`. `epoch` is simpler. I added to my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Use [now() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for the purpose.

The reason for the different outcome of your queries is this:

When you subtract two values of type `date`, the result is an **`integer`** and `abs()` is applicable.
When you subtract two values of type `timestamp` (or just one is a `timestamp`), the result is an **`interval`**, and `abs()` is not applicable. You could substitute with a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expiry > now() THEN expiry - now() ELSE now() - expiry END
```

Or you can [`extract()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) the unix `epoch` from the resulting `interval` like @Craig already demonstrated. I quote: "for interval values, the total number of seconds in the interval". Then you can use `abs()` again:

```
ORDER BY abs(extract(epoch from (expiry - now())));
```

[`age()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) would just add a more human readable representation to the interval by summing up days into months and years for for bigger intervals. But that's beside the point: the value is only used for sorting.

As your column is of type timestamp, you should use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (or `now()`) instead of  `CURRENT_DATE`, or you will get inaccurate results (or even incorrect for "today").

Comment: I don't get it. Using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_DATE` makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Compare with `current_timestamp`

```
SELECT the_timestamp > current_timestamp;
```

The `age` function is probably what you want when comparing them:

```
SELECT age(the_timestamp);
```

eg:

```
regress=# SELECT age(TIMESTAMP '2012-01-01 00:00:00');
      age       
----------------
 8 mons 17 days
(1 row)
```

If you want an absolute distance, use:

```
SELECT abs( extract(epoch from age(the_timestamp)) );
```

Comment: @l0bo "Wrong" how? Show a query and expected results. Do you want to sort on the absolute distance from the `current_timestamp`?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the linked Q&A. Fixed the title.

Comment: @l0b0 Updated then. Looks like someone edited the question so the title explains it properly now anyway.