# Django queryset order_by absolute value

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a queryset that has a `description` attribute and a `balance` attribute.  Currently, when I produce the queryset it is ordered from smallest to largest - -

```
Model.objects.order_by('balance')

#output

Thing1          -120000
Thing2             -300
Thing3             7000
Thing4           100000
```

What I would like to order by is decending absolute value such that the result is:

```
#Desired Output

Thing1          -120000
Thing4           100000
Thing3             7000
Thing2             -300
```

I've tried passing various methods inside the `order_by()` but I think it needs to be an SQL type argument - which I can't figure out.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868706/django-queryset-absolute-value-of-the-annotated-field) which uses a `func expression` when annotating.  I couldn't get it to work with the `order_by` and the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) didn't help much.

Is there a way to order a queryset in such a way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can annotate absolute values and order by annotated value. You can use `-` sign to indicate descending order:

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

Model.objects.annotate(abs_balance=Func(F('balance'), function='ABS')).order_by('-abs_balance')
```

Comment: This throws `1054, "Unknown column '17' in 'order clause'"`.  I'm guessing it's because I'm forming my queryset by a union of two different querysets from the same model - but there is a missing value for the column I'm performing the `order_by` on.  ?

Comment: @BillArmstrong yep, if second querysent doesn't have annotated `abs_balance` value you will get error.

Comment: yep - I can get it to work on the separate querysets, just need to get the union or similar to work together - thanks.

Comment: One final comment...  To get the order from largest `ABS` value to smallest, use a `-` in the attribute.  (e.g., `.order_by('-balance')` )

Comment: Regarding a `.union()` that is then subjected to an `.annotate()` - it current does not work, see this [bug ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26019#no1).

Comment: @neverwalkaloner this fails for me when I try `.annotate(
                distance=Func(F('datetime') - datetime_goal, function='ABS')
            ).order_by(
                'distance'
            )` with `function abs(interval) does not exist`

Comment: @Vidak Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460797/sort-timestamps-including-future-by-absolute-distance-from-now Try to use expressionwrapper to cast output_type for substraction result: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I solved the problem using the question you linked, by using case/when rather than expressionwrapper. I made a separate answer, if you'd like you can add the solution with expressionwrapper, I coulndn't figure it out :D Thanks a lot btw!

Answer (score 8):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885275/1063607)  by @neverwalkaloner is excellent, but doesn't work when dealing with `datetime` objects, e.g. if you want to order objects by distance to some specific timestamp.

For example:

```
queryset.annotate(
    distance=Func(F('datetime') - datetime_goal, function='ABS')
).order_by('distance')
```

fails with `ProgrammingError: function abs(interval) does not exist`, which is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460797/sort-timestamps-including-future-by-absolute-distance-from-now?noredirect=1&lq=1).

In this case, you can use a `Case` expression to simulate absolute value, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When
queryset.annotate(
    distance=Case(
        When(datetime__gte=datetime_goal, then=F('datetime')-datetime_goal),
        When(datetime__lt=datetime_goal, then=datetime_goal-F('datetime')),
    )
).order_by('distance')
```